# What is the difference between pursuing Academia in STEM and the rest of fields?

Tags: phd

everyone. A lot of times I read that there are many differences in academic and graduate life between STEM and the rest (Humanities, Social Sciences, Management, etc). I've even read many people advising not to earn a PhD in Humanities and Social Sciences since getting into a TT position is very hard and there aren't many alternative careers. What do you believe is the difference?

UPDATE: I'm talking about career prospects after completing the PhD.

Comment: I think you mix up two things here: what is the graduate life like for given fields, ad what are the career prospects/ value of a PhD in those field. Maybe you can improve your question by focusing on one.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad, but I want to note this because it is somewhat of an answer in itself.  Mathematics basically works like literature or philosophy, but engineering and medicine are quite different.  Similarly, accounting looks very different from classics.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the question to clarify that I'm talking about career prospects and the value of a PhD and not about life as a graduate student.

Comment: The question is still too broad. In addition to the specific fields (and don't forget the sub-fields and sub-sub-fields, and the sub-sub-sub-fields, etc.) It also depends on your skill set and interests: if you are a brilliant historian but a horrible mathematician, then trying to get a PhD in Maths will not help your career... There are also regional differences in the value of a PhD.

Comment: If you consider doing a PhD it often helps *not* to think of a PhD as "the highest level of education" but as "vocational training for researchers". This is not meant to be derogatory (here in Germany vocational training has more positive connotation than in many other countries), but to describe what will actually happen:you'll receive training to become a researcher. Is that what you want to do with the rest of your (working) life? If yes, what is it that you want to research?